Solving differential equations with sharp corners in the form of Dirac Delta function
Suppose we have the following well behaved differential equations of time $t$
$$ \ddot y + (-\frac{\dot w}{w}+2w)\dot y + w^2y = w^2x.$$
By well behaved it is meant that change in $w$ and scaling the time of $x$ can be fully accounted by scaling time of the solution $y$, where the scaling is given by $\int_0^t w$.
I am interested in changing $w$ abruptly in which case it has a form similar to a Heavyside function, so that $\dot w= \delta_s$ for some $s$. In this case the Dirac Delta function becomes one of the coefficients and the derivative $\dot w$ is taken in a distributional sense. Now, it would appear that we may split the differential equation at the boundary $s$, then at the boundary
$$\dot y_s=0$$
$$y(s)=y(s-)$$
$$\ddot y_s=w_s^2(x_s-y_s),$$
become the new initial conditions for the part beyond the boundary $s$. So, the appearance is that the problem can be solved by forming a new differential equation with new initial conditions beyond the boundary.
A further problem appears on how to discretize the equation. An approximation, for example as given by Euler $\dot w \approx (w_{t+1}-w_{t})/dt$, appears to immediately work even though $w$ is not even differentiable, why is this valid? The three derived conditions can also be used at the boundary, but this seems quite questionable, since they dictate $y$ should remain constant during the jump, which is hard to justify. How to think about this properly and rigorously?
In the answers I welcome references to resources that attack these types of problems.

Where does the equation come from?

@KevinDietrich It is the equation of a standard analog 2nd order low pass filter with variable cutoff frequency $w$. Note the extra term $-\dot w/ w$ due to $w$ not being constant, which guarantees the nice scaling property and hence stability under very weak conditions.
